# Как указать несколько родителей в дженериках?

Tags: java, wildcards

Необходимо сделать утилитный метод, который будет получать три параметра: **time**, **startTime**, **endTime** и при помощи `compareTo()` проверять, что **time** находится в диапазоне **startTime** и **endTime**.

Все три параметра могут быть экземплярами одного из трёх классов: `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` или `LocalDateTime`.

Как должен выглядеть дженерик для такого метода? В данный момент я смог сделать такую сигнатуру:

```
public static <E extends Temporal, T extends Comparable<E>> boolean isBetweenHalfOpen(T time, E startTime, E endTime)
```

Существует ли какая-либо возможность непосредственно указать все три класса, экземплярами которых могут быть передаваемые в метод параметры? Мне нужно что-то такое: `<T extends LocalDate || T extends LocalTime || T extend LocalDateTime>`. Я понимаю, что такой синтаксис невозможен в Java, но суть, надеюсь, выразил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете создавать в Дженериках несколько родителей. Если вы хотите указать несколько родителей то можно создать для этих родителей интерфейс - маркер.
В этом интерфейсе не должно быть никаких методов. Вы просто всеми вашими классами (которые хотите указать в дженерике) реализуете данный интерфейс. И уже в самом дженерике указываете тип наследующий от этого интерфейса.

Comment: А есть ли какая-либо иная возможность решить мою проблему? Т.е. ограничить входные параметры тремя возможными классами, которые не имеют общих интерфейсов, эсклюзивных для них троих?

Comment: Написать 3 перегруженных функции может быть. Для каждого типа.

Comment: к сожалению требования именно такие, чтобы был один метод

Comment: Все это спрятать в одном классе и сделать так чтоб каждая из этих перегруженных функций вызывала одну внутреннюю. Но это не очень красиво. Если там будет 3 класса, то это пол беды, а если будет 10 или больше то это проблема

Comment: Ну тогда только общий интрефейс/абстрактный класс, если один метод. Того что вы написали в вопросе Java не поддерживает

Comment: спасибо, неплохая идея. Видимо, придётся так и делать. Странно, что у дженериков отсутствует возможность множественного наследования, если она действительно отсутствует.